# Issue with relatively simple integral

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble with this integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx/\sqrt(a^2+x^2)^3$$, $a=const$.

I know it looks simple, but I've tried $a^2+x^2=t$, and $\sqrt(a^2+x^2)=t$, and those didn't work.

Comment: Try $x = a\sinh u$.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $x=a\tan \theta$, we have $$dx=\frac{ad\theta}{\cos^2\theta},(a^2+x^2)^{3/2}=\left(\frac{a^2}{\cos^2\theta}\right)^{3/2}=\frac{a^3}{\cos^3\theta}.$$
So,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(a^2+x^2)^{3/2}}=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{(ad\theta)/(\cos^2\theta)}{a^3/(\cos^3\theta)}=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos\theta}{a^2}d\theta.$$
I'm sure that you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this works:

$x=a*tan\theta$

$dx = ad\theta/cos^2\theta$

$\sqrt(a^2+x^2)^3 = a^3/cos^3\theta$.